# Console Application manifest icon is not updated for .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, console-application, favicon

I have a console application using .Net Core 2.1.
I added an icon through Properties -> Application Tab -> Icon and manifest. It displaying only the default ICON instead of new one.

But It works for .net framework console applications. Any idea to resolve it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

This is a planned feature for .NET Core 3.0, which will be able to do this for the app host (.exe) deployed for windows-specific and windows self-contained applications (at least when building on windows). Until then, there is no built-in way to change the icon.

Comment: Thank you, Martin.

Comment: Was this a regression? It was working before with netcore 2.2, suddenly, still on netcore 2.2, it doesn't any longer seem to pick up the icon.

Comment: You probably used a newer SDK (3.0 preview) to build a 2.2 application. This is about the tools used to build rather than the framework version you build for.

Comment: How can you do this with .NET Core 3.0 now?